# Reporting solution/tool to handle 30 billion records for drill down

Tags: bigdata, tableau-api, apache-phoenix, splice-machine

What would be the best options available to handle 30 billions of records for drill down reporting ?

We are using CDH5.8, spark2.2 and planning to use Tableau. Any thoughts how we can design the solution to have prompt data view in reports.

```
Couple of options which we thought of :
1. Jethro and AtScale for Tableau
2. Phoenix + Tableau
3. Splice Machine + Tableau
```

I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

30 billion records may become too much for quick results.
However you can consider using Extract connection instead of a live connection in your tableau server